# Wider device support for ARCore? (Note 8, hint hint)

Tags: arcore

are there any plans to extend ARCore support to a wider range of devices? I'd love to try ARCore on my Samsung Note 8, but the samples I have seen so far don't work, as they are locked to the Nexus and Galaxy 8 devices.

Comment: There are unofficial ways of getting it to work. https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all The calibration is going to be off. So might not work as well.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I will try that out. Hopefully as the Note and Galaxy 8 aren't that different physically and cameralogically, it will work.

Comment: Hi Richard, how well did it work for Note 8?

Answer (score 1):

From their [news announcement](https://www.blog.google/products/google-vr/arcore-augmented-reality-android-scale/):

> ARCore will run on millions of devices, starting today with the Pixel and Samsung’s S8, running 7.0 Nougat and above. We’re targeting 100 million devices at the end of the preview. We’re working with manufacturers like Samsung, Huawei, LG, ASUS and others to make this possible with a consistent bar for quality and high performance.

Initial launch is loosely planned for this winter. Speaking as someone who works on VIO/SLAM systems (but not at Google), new flagship devices like the Note 8 are certainly powerful enough to run ARCore. The bigger difficulty is tight sensor integration. Running VIO requires camera calibration and IMU delay characterization (ie given an accelerometer timestamp and a camera timestamp, how do you align measurements). It's easy enough to do on a device-by-device basis, but large-scale rollout requires significant device study as well as factory process changes.